# How to insert data into database with object oriented PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My `INSERT` statement is not working. The number of rows affected is affected is `0`. Here is my code :

```
<?php

require_once('class.config.php');

class userActions{

    public $link;      

    function __construct(){
        $db_connection = new dbConnection();
        $this->link = $db_connection->connect();   
        return $this->link;
    }

    function registerUsers($username, $password, $ip_address){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name,password,ip_address) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $values = array($username, $password, $ip_address);
        $query->execute($values);
        $counts = $query->rowCount();
        return $counts;
    }
}

$users = new userActions();
echo $users->registerUsers('bob', 'dave123','127.0.0.1');

?>
```

What have I done wrong?

EDIT : this is my class.config.php:

```
class dbConnection{
protected $db_conn;
public $db_host = "localhost:8080";
public $db_user = "root";
public $db_pass = "";
public $db_name = "facebook";

function connect(){
    try{
    $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $this->db_host; dbname = $this->db_name",
    $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
    $this->db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $this->db_conn;    
    }

    catch(PDOException $e){
        return "MySQL error : " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Change your registerUsers function code to below

If you are using `mysqli` then use below

```
function registerUsers($username, $password, $ip_address){
       $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name,password,ip_address) VALUES (?,?,?)");
       $query->bind_param("sss", $username, $password, $ip_address);
       $query->execute();

}
```

**EDIT**

As I see you are using `PDO`.
Try to use like anyone of below

```
function registerUsers($username, $password, $ip_address){
       $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name,password,ip_address) VALUES (:username,:password,:ip_address)");
       $query->bindParam(':username', $username);
       $query->bindParam(':password', $password);
       $query->bindParam(':ip_address', $ip_address);
       $query->execute();
}
```

OR

```
function registerUsers($username, $password, $ip_address){
  $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name,password,ip_address) VALUES (:username,:password,:ip_address)");
  $query->execute(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'ip_address' => $ip_address));
    }
```

I would prefer to use  `bindParam` as it is secure and it replaces my_real_escape_string.

Comment: Why there is "sss" in this line $query->bind_param("sss", $username, $password, $ip_address);

Comment: @AhmetKarabulut It presents type of value that you provide, s means string so in this case it says that you are providing 3 strings($username, $password and $ip_address)

Comment: It binds the parameter to sql query and tells the database what the parameters are. Take a look on https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: It shows me this : Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected. Yes I have tried both solutions. I have also edited my code above

Comment: Seems like your DB connection is not made. Try to print your connection and see what it shows. Is the error field have 0 or anything else.

Comment: How do I print my db connection. Im new to OOP. and I have done `return $this->db_conn;`

Comment: please follow https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: This is the output: PDO Object ( )

Comment: Yes I have and it works in procedural PHP. I removed the spaces too. No luck.

Comment: Its showing me this now: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php try to follow php.net and some advanced php tutorial pages

Comment: so does my code have a logical error or a syntax error?

Comment: My code works now I created a mysqli object not PDO one :`$connect_db = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name );` but I really wanted to make it in a PDO.

Answer (score 0):

this below can can help you to understand how to insert to database via oop programming

**databse class:**

```
public static $con;

public static function connect($hostname , $username , $password , $database)
{
    self::$con = mysqli_connect($hostname , $username , $password , $database) or die('Error: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}
public static function disconnect()
{
    mysqli_close(self::$con);
}
public static function insert($sql , $values)
{
    $values = self::safeValues($values);
    $sql = self::$con->prepare($sql);
    mysqli_set_charset(self::$con , 'UTF8');
    self::bindValues($sql , $values);
    $save = $sql->execute();
    return $save;
}
public function safeValues($values = null)
{
    if($values != null)
    {
        for($i = 0 ; $i < count($values) ; $i++)
        {
            $values[$i] = trim($values[$i]);
            $values[$i] = strip_tags($values[$i]);
            mysqli_real_escape_string(self::$con , $values[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $values;
}
public function bindValues($sql, $values = null)
{
    if ($values != null)
    {
        // Generate the Type String (eg: 'issisd')
        $types = '';
        foreach($values as $value)
        {
            if(is_int($value))
                $types .= 'i';
            elseif (is_float($value))
                $types .= 'd';
            elseif (is_string($value))
                $types .= 's';
            else
                $types .= 'b';
        }
        // Add the Type String as the first Parameter
        $bind_names[] = $types;
        // Loop thru the given Parameters
        for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($values) ; $i++)
        {
            // Create a variable Name
            $bind_name = 'bind'.$i;
            // Add the Parameter to the variable Variable
            $$bind_name = $values[$i];
            // Associate the Variable as an Element in the Array
            $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;
        }
        // Call the Function bind_param with dynamic Parameters
        call_user_func_array(array($sql,'bind_param') , $bind_names);
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

and in your home class you can insert like this:

**home class:**

```
DB::connect('localhost' , 'username' , 'password' , 'database');

DB::insert("INSERT INTO table(field1, field2) VALUES (? , ?)" , [ $val1 , $val2 ] );
```

i hope this can be helpful for you.

Comment: It's better if you try to solve the OP's question by using `PDO` not `Mysqli`

Comment: I am aware of other methods but can you fix the code i'm having trouble with?

Comment: unfortunately i didnt work with PDO

Comment: Then why did you answer my question was - __How to insert data into database with **object oriented PHP**__

Answer (score -1):

So I have solved my code by removing `localhost:8080` with `127.0.0.1` in my class.config.php.